# Analyzing a closure example

Tags: javascript

Looking at this example, I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly happens behind the scenes when we set `outerFunction = null`;. My first thoughts would be that `function outerFunction(){ //nothing }`. However when call `referenceToInnerFunction`, we can still get the monkey value. I'm sure this has something to do with scope but I can't wrap my head around it. Also, how can I fix this so that when I call `referenceToInnerFunction`, I get `null` as well, as oposed to `monkey?`

```
function outerFunction() {
    var outerVar = "monkey";

    function innerFunction() {
        return outerVar;
    }

    return innerFunction;
}

var referenceToInnerFunction = outerFunction();
alert(referenceToInnerFunction());

outerFunction = null;
alert(referenceToInnerFunction());
```

Comment: A closure is a scope which is created  when an inner function code  has access to its outer scope variables.`innerFunction` will always have in its closure access to outerVar. even if you set outerFunction to null.

Comment: Since you create reference to inner function with `var referenceToInnerFunction = outerFunction();` it will be accessible. It's all about references.

Comment: So say I nest another 10 functions inside outFunction. Even if all of them are set to null, and innerFunction is still defined it has acess to all other of the 10 functions and the outerscope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The garbage collector algorithm of modern implementations of javascript consider that something can be garbage collected when it is not reachable. Here `referenceToInnerFunction` keep an access to `outerVar` since

```
var referenceToInnerFunction = outerFunction();
```

So `outerVar` can't possibly be freed as long as you keep something having an access to it.

More here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Answer (score 1):

You have already assigned ReferenceToInnerFunction variable memory space, it does not change even if you change the values that created it.
To reset the variable, you need to set it again

```
ReferenceToInnerFunction = null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set outerFunction to null ,inner function still is bounded/closed by the outer function, hence it can't be garbage collected.
Thats why you can access outervar